# code to check the characteristics between two letters

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is the code written by me to check if there are exactly 3 characters between the letters **'a'** and **'b'** in the string.
I have tried the code with the following three strings:

1. **'La Rob'**
2. **'lake boat'**
3. **'look after baby'**

The code worked for the **first 2 strings, output: True**. However, the **third one is saying: IndexError: string index out of range**. Instead, the third string should cause two output: **False**. I know why is it saying that but can not fix it, what can be a solution here to fix it ?

```
def hi_coder(string):
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if string[i] == 'a' and string[i+4] == 'b':
            return True
    return False
    return string        
print(hi_coder(input()))
```

Comment: Perhaps `if string[i] == 'a' and i+4 < len(string) and string[i+4] == 'b':`?

Comment: why do you think your program is failing in this way? what *exactly* happens when the first instance of `'a'` is less than 3 characters from the end of the string? can you think of a way to check for this case?

Comment: "I know why is it saying that but can not fix it" Okay, so you **already understand** that the problem is that `i+4` may not be a valid index into the string, depending on the value that `i` has each time through the loop. Can you think of a mathematical rule that tells you, which values of `i` will be possible, if we want `i+4` to be a valid index into the string? Therefore, how can we change the loop, to make sure that `i` only has such values? Voting to close as not reproducible, because once the problem is understood, solving it is a matter of basic logic - not a reproducible problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the upper limit for the range you won't run into trouble with Error. If you found an 'a' at the end of the string it makes no sense to look four characters further as it is the end of the string and there are no more characters there.

```
def hi_coder(string):
    for i in range(len(string)-4): # <<< CHANGED 
        if string[i] == 'a' and string[i+4] == 'b':
            return True
    return False
    return string        
print(hi_coder(input()))
```